# mmap and memcpy usage and Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mmap, memcpy, coredump

I have two files and I want to copy one file content to other using memcpy. But I get this error `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. My main

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
    int d1;
    int d2;
    char *a;
    char *b;
    d1 = da_open_r(argv[1]); // open file READ ONLY
    d2 = da_open_w(argv[2]); //  open file to WRITE
    a = (char*)da_mmap(d1); // map first file
    b = (char*)da_mmap(d2); // map second file
    memcpy(b, a, 10); // I think this line is bad
    kp_test_munamp(a, 10 ); // 
    kp_test_munamp(b, 10 );
    kp_test_close(d1); // close 1 file
    kp_test_close(d2); // close 2 file
    return 0;
}
```

and here are my `da_mmap` and `kp_test_munamp`

```
void *da_mmap(int d){
    mmap(NULL, 10, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, d, 0);
}

int kp_test_munamp( void *a, int size ){
   int rv;
   rv = munmap( a, size );
   if( rv != 0 ){
      puts( "munmap failed" );
      abort();
   }
   return 1;
}
```

I have been trying to fix this almost two hours, but still I don't know what's wrong.
EDIT my full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

int da_open_r(const char *name);
int da_open_w(const char *name);
void *da_mmap(int d);
int kp_test_munamp( void *a, int size );
int kp_test_close(int fd);

int da_open_r(const char *name){
    int dskr;
    dskr = open( name, O_RDWR );
    if( dskr == -1 ){
      perror( name );
      exit( 255 );
    }
    printf( "dskr1 = %d\n", dskr );
    return dskr;
}

int da_open_w(const char *name){
    int dskr;
    dskr = open( name, O_RDWR );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
      perror( name );
      exit( 255 );
   }
   printf( "dskr2 = %d\n", dskr );
   return dskr;
}

void *da_mmap(int d){
     void *a = NULL;
     a = mmap(NULL, 10, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, d, 0);
     if( a == MAP_FAILED ){
          perror( "mmap failed" );
          abort();
     }
     return a;
}

int kp_test_munamp( void *a, int size ){
   int rv;
   rv = munmap( a, size );
   if( rv == -1 ){
      puts( "munmap failed" );
      abort();
   }
   return 1;
}

int kp_test_close(int fd){
   int rv;
   rv = close( fd );
   if( rv != 0 ) perror ( "close() failed" );
   else puts( "closed" );
   return rv;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
    int d1;
    int d2;
    char *a;
    char *b;
    d1 = da_open_r(argv[1]); // read only
    d2 = da_open_w(argv[2]); //  WRITE
    a = (char*)da_mmap(d1);
    b = (char*)da_mmap(d2);
    memcpy(b, a, 10); // I think this line is bad
    kp_test_munamp(a, 10 );
    kp_test_munamp(b, 10 );
    kp_test_close(d1);
    kp_test_close(d2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you checking if all your file related operations are successful?

Comment: Does the code compile without warnings when using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`?

Comment: Did you trace your code inside a debugger to identify the source line where it crashes? Compile using option `-g` then run `gbd yourprogramname`, do a `b main <enter>` then a `r <enter>` and then trace line by line using `t <enter>`. You'll love it.

Comment: I get no stack! But why? I thought that all variabes in main go on stack. How is it possible that there are nos stack!?

Comment: There might be stale shared memory segments hanging around, as leftovers from various test runs of your program. Inspect this using the command line tool `ipcs`. Remove those using `ipcrm`.

Answer (score 1):

`da_mmap()` does not return anything! Which leads to the values of `a` and `b` being garbage and with this most probably pointing to invalid memory, which in turn makes `memcpy()` fail when acting on it.

Add  return statement

```
void * da_mmap(int d) {
  return mmap(NULL, 10, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, d, 0);
}
```

---

Also you should test the outcome of the mapping by doing:

```
{
  void * pvtmp = da_mmap(d1); // map first file
  if (MAP_FAILED == pvtmp)
  {
    perror("da_mmap() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  a = pvtmp;
}
```

The same for `b`.

---

Referring the wrapper around `munmap()`. Correct error testing here. However by convention success is indicated by returning `0` (failure by returning `-1`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But still I got the same problem.

Comment: I get the same error Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Comment: @David: Are you sure you recompiled everything, sry?

Comment: Yes. Also I edited my question and paste all my code.

Comment: @David: Cannot reproduce on my side, your code works.